# Scala type inference involving case statement and type members

Tags: scala, type-inference

I'm sorry, but I couldn't think of a better title (suggestions welcome).

Basically I have a class hierarchy and the subclasses have a type member, indicating "to which type they should map". Then I want to have a class that implements some kind of heterogeneous map for these types. See the following code as an example.

My question is whether (and how) I can get this to work without resorting to casting. If it can't work, please explain why.

```
trait A {
  type Result
}

case class AInt(id: String) extends A {
  type Result = Int
}

case class AString(id: String) extends A {
  type Result = String
}

class AStore {
  val mapInt = new collection.mutable.HashMap[String,Int]()
  val mapString = new collection.mutable.HashMap[String,String]()

  def put[T <: A](t: T, result: T#Result) {
    t match {
      case AInt(id) => mapInt(id) = result
      case AString(id) => mapString(id) = result
    }
  }

  def get[T <: A](t: T): T#Result = t match {
    case AInt(id) => mapInt(id)
    case AString(id) => mapString(id)
  }
}
```

Trying to compile this yields the following error message:

```
19: error: type mismatch;
 found   : T#Result
 required: Int
      case AInt(id) => mapInt(id) = result
                                    ^
20: error: type mismatch;
 found   : T#Result
 required: String
      case AString(id) => mapString(id) = result
                                          ^
25: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: T#Result
    case AInt(id) => mapInt(id)
                           ^
26: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String
 required: T#Result
    case AString(id) => mapString(id)
                                 ^
four errors found
```

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't work for a simple reason: in

```
  def put[T <: A](t: T, result: T#Result) {
    t match {
      case AInt(id) => mapInt(id) = result
      case AString(id) => mapString(id) = result
    }
  }
```

`T`'s scope is the entire method definition, so you can't have different `T#Result` in different branches.

You can look into [GADTs](http://lambdalog.seanseefried.com/posts/2011-11-22-gadts-in-scala.html).

This would be your example with encoding given by the linked post:

```
trait A[Result] {
  def id: String
}

case class AInt(id: String) extends A[Int]

case class AString(id: String) extends A[String]

class AStore {
  val mapInt = new collection.mutable.HashMap[String,Int]()
  val mapString = new collection.mutable.HashMap[String,String]()

  def put[Result](t: A[Result], result: Result) {
    t match {
      case AInt(id) => mapInt(id) = result
      case AString(id) => mapString(id) = result
    }
  }

  def get[Result](t: A[Result]): Result = t match {
    case AInt(id) => mapInt(id)
    case AString(id) => mapString(id)
  }
}
```

Comment: So scalac can't figure out which `case` the method will take. But how can I translate the provided link to my use case. I don't really see the difference between the `evalAny` method and my code. In particular, the type parameter of my methods should bind on each invocation. Just as it is stated for the `evalAny` method.

Comment: So your explanation means that type inference as implemented in Scala is too weak?

Comment: See http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0-latest/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html#gadt for explanation in Haskell.

Comment: No. This isn't really related to type inference. What you want is _type refinement_.

Comment: I think I understand the provided Haskell link (thanks). It says, that pattern matching will cause a refinement of the type of `eval`. Thus if we go down the int literal match, the signature will be refined to `eval :: Term Int -> Int`. This seems to be exactly what I want. And your example looks the same as mine, but you are using type parameters instead of type members. So why doesn't it work with type members? Or to put it your way: Why isn't `Result`'s scope the entire method definition in contrast to `T`?

Comment: Hmm.... Let me put it this way. With type members you could call `get[A](AInt(""))`, which should return `A#Result`. `A#Result` is an abstract type, not `Int` or `String`. But `mapInt("")` returns an `Int`, so that's an error. With type parameters you can't get a mismatch like this (try it!), so types can be refined.

Comment: Then why doesn't `def get[R](t: A {type Result=R}):R` work? Now the type parameter of the method `R` refers to the result type. Somehow I don't realize why type parameters (of class `A`) are refined but type members not? Is it the case that for the refinement to work, a value with the to be refined type must be used as a subject to a pattern match, no indirection allowed? Because somehow I have the impression that it should be possible to type check the methods in the OP. I don't see how e.g. the method `get` of my example could fail to return a value of type `T#Result`.

Comment: Yes, `def get[R](t: A {type Result=R}):R` looks to me like it should work. Unfortunately, I don't know how precisely type refinement is implemented in Scala and what are the limitations.

Comment: I awarded you the bounty since there was no other answer and you did a good job. But somehow I'm left unsatisfied. I still don't know whether my initial design had an inherent flaw or whether it didn't work because the inference is not strong enough.